# Best way to distribute a python script

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-wheel

I wrote a relatively simple python script to help a friend process and analyze data.  The script reads some xls files into pandas dataframes and writes out the results to an excel sheet.  I used argprase to set some options and specify where the source files are.  To make it simple, I created a GUI with Gooey.  As a result there are a handful of module dependencies which I've listed below.

```
DateTime (4.1.1)
Gooey (0.9.2.3)
natsort (5.0.1)
numpy (1.11.2)
pandas (0.19.1)
pip (9.0.1)
PyInstaller (3.2)
python-dateutil (2.6.0)
pytz (2016.7)
scipy (0.18.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.30.0a0)
wxPython (3.0.2.0)
xlrd (1.0.0)
XlsxWriter (0.9.3)
```

The part I'm trying to figure out the best and most self-contained way to share this package with my friend.  She is not python savvy at all and doesn't even really know what the command line is (Hence my building a GUI).

To be honest, my head is spinning with all the potential options out there ...

wheels, eggs, .pyc, setuptools, cython, py2app, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx_freeze, pip wheel ...

I've been mainly try to make an exe for her Windows computer and an .app for her Mac using pyinstaller but I've not been able to get either to work.  Is that the best way to go, or is there an easier way to distribute this little program?

Comment: I can try to help regarding both py2app and py2exe if you show us what errors you get.

Comment: with py2app I'm getting a window that says "at_analyzer Error" Open Console or Terminate.  When I look at the console I get " Nov 21 13:07:40 Alexs-MacBook-Pro-Retina at_analyzer[74794]: at_analyzer Error
Nov 21 13:07:48 Alexs-MacBook-Pro-Retina com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.pythonmac.unspecified.at_analyzer.9836[74794]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255

Comment: For this kind of dependencies, I would try https://github.com/conda/constructor even if it's rather experimental.

Comment: Remote desktop?  In the short term, you can just get it done and move on with your life; but in the long term it will mean they can't do anything for themselves and come back and ask you to do everything computery they can ever think of.  Just how much do you like this girl?

Comment: @Zah I'm not using Conda.  My python is installed with homebrew.

Comment: @JohnMee Remote Desktop doesn't really seem like an option.  If I made it an ipython notebook and put it online could it spawn a GUI?

Comment: maybe not the answer you expect, but rather than going into the intricate path of py2exe and other folks, maybe just make your program a webapp ?

Comment: @StephaneMartin A webapp might be a good solution.  I'm just not familiar with the particulars on how to make that happen.  Keep in mind I've got to read files from a local machine and hand the user back a data file.  Any suggestions on a framework to make that happen?

Comment: #rant  It seems a little crazy to me that if Python is a general-purpose programming language that there isn't an easy way to give someone the programs you've made without them having to do a whole bunch of work to use them.  That's expected in high level languages like matlab or R, but I thought the promise of Python was that it was more portable.  :-|

Comment: How far did you go with pyinstaller? Did it give you an .exe that crashes? You can run that from the command line (provided that you haven't used the --windowed option) and post the error.